# Unable to recover lost login

Tags: debian, login, password, passwd, shadow

I'm running [Bananian linux](http://www.lemaker.org/product-bananapro-download-25.html) on my [Banana Pro](http://wiki.lemaker.org/BananaPro/Pi:Quick_Start) recently I changed some config settings but quit it with `ctrl + c` without finishing editing all the config settings. After restart I am unable to login with default login - "root", I get the error `incorrect login` every time I try.

I tried checking my username in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

```
/etc/passwd file

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:103:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:104:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:105:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:106:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
ntp:x:104:109::/home/ntp:/bin/false
sshd:x:105:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

.

```
/etc/shadow file

root:$6$9KzHxAiY$L8WtC4E1KoZYbzaxMCK4AhpVGfS3oKLNdn1YjIbunGcQDJLm8GwjRy1fXU7vhHh7DrR8hNChqPnaoL76efh/f/:14610:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
sys:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
games:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
man:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
mail:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
news:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
uucp:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
proxy:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
www-data:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
backup:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
list:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
irc:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
gnats:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
nobody:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
systemd-timesync:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
systemd-network:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
systemd-resolve:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
systemd-bus-proxy:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
ntp:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
sshd:*:16628:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you seem to have access to `/etc/shadow` as a privileged user (sudo?), do

```
sudo passwd root
```

If on the other hand, you are editing the filesystem in the MicroSD card in another machine, just edit out the root password in `/etc/shadow`. Delete the encrypted password field as in:

```
root::14610:0:99999:7:::
```

Then you will be able to enter as root in the console, press ENTER when asked for the password, and change it once you login with `passwd`.